# Has a soccer team ever started a match a man down?

Tags: football

I'm wondering if there's some way that a club could be penalized so that they could only start 10 men.

I'm thinking primarily Premier League, but I'd be interested if it happened in Bundesliga, Serie A, or La Liga.

Comment: https://guernseypress.com/news/2008/02/06/losing-holders-walk-off/ - This team started their league match with 9. They had ten men originally, but the referee didn't turn up and they agreed for one of their team to be the ref

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No - while the referee's authority starts when they enter the field for the pre-match inspection ([Law 5.3](https://www.theifab.com/laws/latest/the-referee/#powers-and-duties)) and they can send off players who commit offences before the match starts, that results only in the player not being able to take part in the match, not the team starting with 10 players. Quoting [Law 3.6](https://www.theifab.com/laws/latest/the-players/#players-and-substitutes-sent-off):

> A player who is sent off:
>
> - before submission of the team list cannot be named on the team list in
>   any capacity
> - after being named on the team list and before kick-off may be replaced by a named substitute, who cannot be replaced; the number of substitutions the
>   team can make is not reduced
> - after the kick-off cannot be replaced

Comment: What happens if so many players get sent off that the team only has ten remaining?

Comment: @Mark as long as there are at least 7 remaining in a team, the match can start / continue.